# WiFi connected but not working after a while, unless i turn it off and on again (macosx sierra)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, airport

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) MacOsX Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32) and I have a weird issue with my office's WLAN: I can connect to WiFi, and navigate on internet, then (usually after around one minute) it stops working: I'm still connected (the top-right icon shows the wifi interface it's still on and connected to the network), but pages don't load anymore and request end up in timeout errors. If I turn WiFi off and on again everything works again for a while then it stops and I have to turn wifi off/on again. So the loop takes place.

I can't figure out what the problem is and isolate it, everything seems ok. I guess this is likely a network (router) problem, since it only happens at work, but my colleagues apparently don't have this problem. Plus, if it were a routing problem, why does everything works again after a simple wifi interface reconnection laptop side i.e. without doing anything router-side?

EDIT:
I've done some test and it turns out after apparently loosing connectivity to internet it's still possible to ping public hosts. So, I guess, network is up,  DNS work correctly, and the problem should be limited to http data forwarding on port 80 (so, likely a routing problem)

Comment: Have you contacted your employer's IT team in an attempt to fix the problem? It is unclear if your laptop disconnects after a minute _every time_ you connect to wifi, or if your laptop stays connected once you toggle wifi off/on. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Hi @IconDaemon I've edited the question as you suggested. The laptop **always** looses connection to internet (not to wifi) after a while, regardless of how many times i'vbe turned wifi/on/off again. Hope now it's clearer.

Comment: I would suggest that you go to `System Preferences > Network > Advanced... button` and make sure this misbehaving network is at the top of the Preferred Networks list. Another suggestion would be to delete this troublesome network from this list and re-create it. I find that some wifi problems disappear if you try these two suggestions. If it works, let me know and I'll make this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Network in System Preferences. Go to Advanced, and check the DNS Servers. You should have 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, add those if they are not on there. Now check if your ipv4 is set to DHCP, and turn off ipv6 if it is on.

Comment: OP may not be able to use Google's DNS servers because this wifi problem only occurs when he is connected with his employer's Wifi network, which may disallow accessing outside services.

Comment: So dns is not a problem, as the isp shouldve assigned one, but does he have both dns servers, for work and at home? This might be the problem? Not sure really

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question with further information (should not be a DNS problem)